# how to initialize object of js file in html

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

how to initialize a js file in html.
I have a javascript written file. Inside which I have bind data with html div.
but i am not able to initialize it.
I did this way:

```
Event.observe(window, "load", Application_init);
function Application_init() {
    //Emds.Orders.StaticOrderdetail = new StaticOrderdetails();
    window.OrderControl1 = new StaticOrderdetails();
}
```

Comment: [Learn how **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and then tell us what the error message is.

Comment: Event.observe(window, "load", Application_init); observe is not a function .. this is the error in firebug..

Comment: what version of PrototypeJS? Make sure you run this after prototype has been loaded